# merge rows together into one cell (into a tuple) for specifc columns

Tags: python, pandas, row

say i have a table like below: where under id 2 for exampple this row just shows the history of status and date for that id.

```
 *id*,             *status*,                      *date*,               *Type*  
        2             dissolved                   2016/03/19                T1 
        nan           active                         NaT                    nan
        3             dissolved                  2016/03/19,                T3 
        nan           active                     2012/03/16                 nan
        4             in liquidation,            2017/03/19                 T2 
        nan           dissolved,                      NaT                   nan
```

what i want to do is combine the rows by id so that for instance for first id = 2 i get:

```
 *id*,             *status*,                      *date*,               *Type*  
   2             [dissolved,active]              [2016/03/19,None]          T1
```

i have tried:

```
 data.groupby(['id']).agg(lambda x: tuple(x)).applymap(list).reset_index()
```

but this puts id column as [2,nan] when all i want is 2. how do i go about this? i only want list format for my status and date values not to tuple all of them up!

Input df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,"dissolved","2016/03/19","T1" ],
            [float("nan"),"active","NaT",float("nan")],
            [3,"dissolved","2016/03/19","T3" ],
            [float("nan"),"active","2012/03/16",float("nan")],
            [4,"in liquidation","2017/03/19","T2" ],
            [float("nan"),"dissolved","NaT",float("nan")]],columns = ["id","status","date","Type"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,"dissolved","2016/03/19","T1" ],
            [float("nan"),"active","NaT",float("nan")],
            [3,"dissolved","2016/03/19","T3" ],
            [float("nan"),"active","2012/03/16",float("nan")],
            [4,"in liquidation","2017/03/19","T2" ],
            [float("nan"),"dissolved","NaT",float("nan")]],columns = ["id","status","date","Type"])
df = df.ffill()
df["status"] = df["status"]  + ","
df["date"] = df["date"]  + ","
df2 = df.groupby(["id","Type"]).sum()
df2["status"] = df2["status"].apply(lambda x: x.split(",")[0:len(x.split(","))-1])
df2["date"] = df2["date"].apply(lambda x: x.split(",")[0:len(x.split(","))-1])
df2
```

Depending on your dataset maybe you will need to adapt it a bit. It outputs the following:

```
          status                        date
id  Type        
2.0 T1   [dissolved, active]           [2016/03/19, NaT]
3.0 T3   [dissolved, active]           [2016/03/19, 2012/03/16]
4.0 T2   [in liquidation, dissolved]   [2017/03/19, NaT]
```

Comment: when i do this nothing gets returned the output it '_'

Comment: i do print it, that is what i mean, when i print it, the output is : '_'

Comment: You should be doing something wrong, when I execute the above code, I obtain the above output...Please provide more details.